# How do I take a screenshot without the shadow behind it?

Tags: screen-capture

If I take a screenshot with <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, then I get one of the two images:
[image: blue-with-focus]
[image: blue-wo-focus]

Either way the saved image is surrounded by the shadow halo. I could then edit it out by hand (using Preview) to discard the shadow, or I could use <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> and try to pinpoint the boundary by hand, but neither lets me get a pixel-perfect boundary easily.

Is there a convenient way to save a window without its shadow?

Comment: Quick solution as posted by @[asherkin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/69605/asherkin) [below](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120017/14994): Hold the Option key while clicking (after doing the Cmd-Shift-4, Space dance) and the saved screenshot will not have the drop shadow !

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can disable the shadow added when capturing an entire window by executing the following command from the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool TRUE
```

You'll need to reboot or restart the UIServer for the changes to take effect:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

You can undo this preference and re-enable shadows by executing the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool FALSE; killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Technically, a fresh install of OSX doesn't have that default at all. Running `defaults read com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow` gives you `The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screencapture, disable-shadow) does not exist`. Therefore the more accurate way to undo the change is with `defaults delete com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow`.

Comment: Be sure to check out the better answer! http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120017/41827

Comment: works on macOS Sierra

Comment: Don't bother changing the settings. Check the answer below.

Comment: FWIW this stopped working for me on Catalina. I had to resort to the `option` key solution.

Comment: This no longer works in Monterey for me. (However the `option` answer below does)

Comment: On, Ventura 13.1 `defaults write …` works OK :-)

Answer (score 106):

I know this is an old question - but I can never find this information when searching for it (just the information in the accepted answer to turn it off globally), and end up just trying random keys each time.

If you hold <kbd>option</kbd> while clicking (after doing the <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> dance), the saved screenshot will not have the drop shadow.

I'm unsure if this only applies to Mountain Lion and later.

Comment: Works in Mavericks. That's awesome!

Comment: Works in 10.8.5. Very convenient.

Comment: Superb - easiest answer by far!

Comment: Works in El Capitan as well!

Comment: This is the real answer. @Calaf you should changed your choice if possible.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thx!

Comment: Works in macOS Sierra too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the simplest and working solution.

Comment: Marvelous!!! You should get a prize for revealing this.

Comment: Superb!! I wonder what would be Steve Jobs answer to the question: How can a regular user find out about these keyboard shortcuts without reading endless help files or googling it??

Answer (score 24):

Another option is to use `screencapture`:

```
screencapture -oic
```

`-o` disables shadows, `-i` captures an area, and `-c` copies the image to the clipboard.

This would use a timer of 5 seconds and save the image to a file:

```
screencapture -oi -T5 /tmp/screencapture.png
```

Run `screencapture -h` to list all options:

```
$ screencapture -h
screencapture: illegal option -- h
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive modes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

You can also use [toggle-osx-shadows](https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows) to disable shadows everywhere in OS X:

`git clone https://github.com/pufuwozu/toggle-osx-shadows.git;cd toggle-osx-shadows;make;mv toggle-osx-shadows /usr/local/bin;toggle-osx-shadows`

Comment: also very useful when one wants to capture from a script.

Answer (score 12):

Just use <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, and hold down <kbd>option</kbd> when you click to select the window.

Comment: Why did nobody see this before?

Comment: The ultimate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another useful option is to use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html). Go to TinkerTool and under the General tab, you'll find an option to disable shadows *only* when taking screenshots (along with several other related options):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while taking a window screen shot.

Comment: works for Ventura 13.1